# Can particular item be closed REST API

Tags: rest, api

I want to implement a REST endpoint to figure out whether a particular item can be closed. How can I do it properly from the point of view of REST design?

/items/canbeclosed - sounds ugly

maybe something like

/items/status but I have already status endpoint used for another purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several different possibilities depending on what you want to do specifically.

For getting whether a particular item can be closed, retrieve the item and have a field that answers this question:

`GET /items/{itemNumber}`

```
{
    "canBeClosed": true,
    ...
}
```

You could also use a subresource for that particular field:

`GET /items/{itemNumber}/can-be-closed`

```
true
```

This would also be "resty" but it's only helpful in some edge cases. You wouldn't want to make a call over the network for every little piece of information. This would result in bad performance.

Note that the solutions above point to a single resource identified by its ID. Have a look at [restapitutorial.com](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) for the difference between collection resources and item resources.

Maybe you want to get a list of the items which are closable:

`GET /items?closable=true`

In this case I'd like using a matrix param more:

`GET /items;closable=true`

Matrix params are much like query params except that they are bound to a particular path element rather than to the end result. So you can have something like this:

`GET /customers;country=Germany/orders`

which would return the orders of customers living in Germany. This is not possible with query params as they are always added to the end. So in my eyes they are better for paging and sorting while matrix params are better for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do it properly from the point of view of REST design?

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI.

It might help to think about what's true of the items *now*, rather than thinking about which actions are possible.  For instance, if the items "can be closed" because they are "completed", then `/items?completed` or `/items/completed` or even '/completedItems' might be reasonable spellings.

Alternatively, perhaps these are tasks, sitting in a task queue, with different queues set up for your different stages.  So something like `/stages/closeItem/tasks` might be the right thing.

Your touchstone, as with all things REST, is to imagine your API as a web site.  If you had to navigate to a web page to access this information, what would the identifier of the web page be?  and there you go.